# How can an element of an array be used as a variable name for some of the rest of the data?

Tags: python, string, variables, matrix

I'm trying to get the top entry (string) in a matrix of data to be the variable name for the rest of the (numerical) data in each column.  I've used the following to open the file and create the matrix.

```
with open('x.dat', 'r') as f:
    row = 0
    for line in f:
        words = line.split(',')
        for col in range(len(words)):
            DataMatrix[row][col] = words[col] 
        row += 1
f.close()
```

However, i can't see how to take the string and have it be recognized as a variable name for the "list" of data which will be filled by the column of numerics.  This has got to be simpler than I'm making it.  Any help?

The data file looks like: ... (can't seem to get the format to show correctly, but each [] is a row and the rows are stacked on top of one another)
    ['% Time','FrameNo','Version','X','Y','Z',…]
    ['66266.265514','948780','2.5','64','0','30'…]
    [66266.298785','948785', 2.5','63','0','32',…]
     …

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Can you give us some example data and example output?

Comment: Do you mean that the first row of data is a list of column names which you want it to become the name of list variable in your script consisting of all the values from that column in the rest of the rows?

Comment: martineau - Exactly!  The first row of the data file has string entries that I want to have become the variable name of a list that will consist of all the entries in their column.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [vars](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) built-in function of python. This will give you a `dict` representing the variables in scope.

I don't follow the code in your example enough to add this solution into it, but here is an example using vars that might help:

```
# Set up some data (which would actually be read from a file in your example)
headers = ['item', 'quantity', 'cost']
data = [['dress', 'purse', 'puppy'], [1, 2, 15], [27.00, 15.00, 2.00]]

for i in range(len(headers)):
  name = headers[i]
  value = list()
  for data_item in data[i]:
    value.append(data_item)
  # This sets the name of the header to the name of a variable
  vars()[name] = value

# Print to prove that vars() worked
print 'Items', item
print 'Quantities', quantity
print 'Costs', cost
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Items ['dress', 'purse', 'puppy']
Quantities [1, 2, 15]
Costs [27.0, 15.0, 2.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function

```
with open('x.dat', 'r') as f:
    row = 0
    for line in f:
        words = line.split(',')
        for col in range(len(words)):
            DataMatrix[row][int(col)] = words[int(col)] 
        row += 1
f.close()
```

Alternatively, you could do a [CSV reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to make this marginally easier.

```
with open('x.dat', 'rb') as csvfile:
    theReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    row=0;
    for line in theReader:
        row+=1
        for col in range(len(line)):
             DataMatrix[row][int(col)] = words[int(col)]
```

Comment: `delimiter=','` is redundant - and at least use `enumerate(theReader, start=1)` ? (but until the OP clarifies - we've no idea if this is correct or not!)

Comment: True enough, but I'm inclined to give the delimiter as an option until the OP gives an idea.

Comment: I'm going for the `line.split(',')` as a give-away?

Comment: I'm new to Python - not sure if I get this, but I the "col" seems to already be an integer since it's in the "range(len(words))".  So using "int" does not seem to change the results.  The code I posted works,... I just want additional code to handle the DataMatrix entries so I can use one of its entries as a variable name for the remainder of values in the column of the matrix.

Comment: @Mark: That is true enough, you don't need to use `int(col)`, but at the very least, it would need to be done to use it as an index to the array. You might also look into dictionaries.

Comment: The results change if the ',' is not included.  I have commas n he data separating the entries.  If I don't use that I don't get the entries out as separte "word" entries.  However, the real question is how to get one of those entries to act as a vaiable name for the rest of the data in the column.